# Problem using both include and attributes in findAll() query in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I searched on the internet a common issue but I did not find anything so I post the question here.

I am using Sequelize for Node and I am trying to query my PostgreSQL database to find all the objects in a specific table. However, I would like to be able to replace de foreign keys by data from their linked table (In other words, join tables and remove the ids). I managed to do this by using both the "include" option to join the table and the "attributes" option to unselect the Id and only keep the joined value, but since I have a hasMany relationship, I get an error when executing the query.

Here is the options I use :

```
options = {
        include: [
            {
                model: models.ProviderType,
                attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                as: 'providerType',
            },
            {
                model: models.SavingProduct,
                attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                as: 'savingProducts',
            },
        ],
        attributes: [
            'id',
            'name',
            'siteUrl',
            'logoPath',
            'createdAt',
            'updatedAt',
            'deletedAt',
        ],
    }
```

And it executed the following query :

```
SELECT "Provider".*, "providerType"."id" AS "providerType.id", "providerType"."name" AS "providerType.name", "savingProducts"."id" AS "savingProducts.id", "savingProducts"."name" AS "savingProducts.name"
FROM (
SELECT "Provider"."id", "Provider"."name", "Provider"."siteUrl", "Provider"."logoPath", "Provider"."createdAt", "Provider"."updatedAt", "Provider"."deletedAt" 
FROM "Provider" AS "Provider" 
WHERE "Provider"."deletedAt" IS NULL 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
) AS "Provider" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ProviderType" AS "providerType" ON "Provider"."providerTypeId" = "providerType"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "SavingProduct" AS "savingProducts" ON "Provider"."id" = "savingProducts"."providerId" AND ("savingProducts"."deletedAt" IS NULL);
```

The error thrown is : "column Provider.providerTypeId does not exist". It is logical because, when selecting the embedded SELECT, I do not select Provider.providerTypeId as I don't want this column to be returned, and because of that, when trying to JOIN the tables, SQL do not find this column and return an error.

In other words, Sequelize first select the wanted values and then join while I would like it to do the opposite, ie join the tables and then select only the asked columns.

So I understand the error but I don't find any way to replace the foreign keys by data from the linked tables. It is possible I did not take the right direction to do that so if you see something easier and cleaner, I would really appreciate!

Followed are the models definition :

For Provider

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Provider = sequelize.define('Provider', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        siteUrl: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        logoPath: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
    });
    Provider.associate = (models) => {
        Provider.belongsTo(models.ProviderType, { as: 'providerType' });
        Provider.hasMany(models.SavingProduct, { as: 'savingProducts', foreignKey: 'providerId' });
    };
    return Provider;
};
```

For SavingProduct

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const SavingProduct = sequelize.define('SavingProduct', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
    });
    SavingProduct.associate = (models) => {
        SavingProduct.belongsTo(models.Provider, { as: 'provider', foreignKey: 'providerId' });
    };
    return SavingProduct;
};
```

Please do not hesitate to tell me if I am not clear, I would be happy to provide you with more informations.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to declare an association as Provider.belongsTo(models.ProviderType, { as: 'providerType', foreignKey: 'provider_type_id' })

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Anatoly, it did not change anything Actually, I succeeded to make it work by using the option seperate=true that uses two queries instead of only one. It is not optimal as it makes more calls to the database, but it is the only solution I found.